# Regular Expression (Regex): How to find a attribute is missing in a multi line html tag

Tags: regex, attributes, tags

```
<g:select
                                    name="securityQuestionOne"
                                    id="systemSecurityQuestionOne"                                   
                                    optionKey="question"
                                    optionValue="question"
                                    value="${userPreference.securityQuestionOne}"/>
```

Here i want to find how many of <g:select tag has missing from attribute.
I want to exclude which has from tag like

```
<g:select
                                    name="securityQuestionOne"
                                    id="systemSecurityQuestionOne"
                                    from="${securityQuestionList}" noSelection="['null':'-Select Question One-']"
                                    optionKey="question"
                                    optionValue="question"
                                    value="${userPreference.securityQuestionOne}"/>
```

so that i can add empty from tag like from="" where it is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer

```
(?s)<g:select((?!from).)*?/>
```